# Toad for Oracle, No valid Oracle clients found. You need at least one 64-bit client properly configured

Tags: oracle, toad

I get this error when I launch Toad for Oracle.

```
No valid Oracle clients found. You need at least one 64-bit client properly configured.
```

This has been happening since I upgraded the Oracle Client to Oracle 12c from 11g.

[image]

Here is what I have done so far to try to resolve it based on internet research:

1. I checked the path variable, it's currently set to C:\xyz\Oracle\ora12.1\client_2\bin, and there is an Oracle installation at this path.
2. I checked the TNS_ADMIN variable, it is currently set to C:\xyz\Oracle\ora12.1\client_2\network\admin. This also appears to be valid and correct, there is a tnsnames.ora file under this path.

SQL Plus works without issues, and Oracle SQL Developer also works without issues.

Is there anything else I can try to resolve this issue? Unfortunately, uninstalling and reinstalling Toad is not an option at this point as I do not have access to a new setup.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a 64-bit Oracle client installation and not a 32-bit Oracle client installation?

Comment: Obviously you have the 64-bit version of TOAD but you installed the 32-bit Oracle Client. Install the 32-bit version of Oracle. If you like to install both, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to not having the Oracle Database installed on your computer.

You can download the database here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html

Once the zip file is downloaded and extracted, run setup.exe. Once that is complete, the Oracle DB will be installed on your machine and the error will no longer appear.

Comment: I think the message "No valid Oracle clients found." clearly indicates that a Client is missing, not the database.

Comment: Be that as it may, I had the same error and redownloading the database fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

With TOAD you need to have oracle client installed on your computer and you must configure the related TNSNAMES.ORA to connect to the server.
If you use SQLDeveloper you can do without oracle client installation.